# sum before joining two table

Tags: sql, join

```
CREATE TABLE Daily
    ([DATE] datetime, [sales] int)
;

INSERT INTO Daily
    ([DATE], [sales])
VALUES
    ('2012-01-01 00:00:00', 1),
    ('2012-01-02 00:00:00', 2),
    ('2012-01-03 00:00:00', 3),
    ('2012-01-04 00:00:00', 4),
    ('2012-01-05 00:00:00', 5),
    ('2012-01-06 00:00:00', 6),
    ('2012-01-06 00:00:00', 5),
    ('2012-01-07 00:00:00', 7),
    ('2012-01-08 00:00:00', 8),
    ('2012-01-09 00:00:00', 9),
    ('2012-01-10 00:00:00', 10),
    ('2012-01-11 00:00:00', 11),
    ('2012-01-12 00:00:00', 12),
    ('2012-01-13 00:00:00', 13),
    ('2012-01-14 00:00:00', 14),
    ('2012-01-15 00:00:00', 15),
    ('2012-01-16 00:00:00', 16)
;

CREATE TABLE Weekly
    ([Weekly] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Weekly
    ([Weekly])
VALUES
    ('2012-01-07 00:00:00'),
    ('2012-01-14 00:00:00'),
    ('2012-01-21 00:00:00')
;
```

i want the final output

```
Sales       
1/7/2012        33
1/14/2012       77
```

any help on this would be appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, What are you trying to achieve? And which SQL is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly reccommend against storing this in a table, if any of your daily data changes your weekly data will need to be changed to or it will be wrong, instead create a view as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW Weekly 
AS
    SELECT  WeekEnd = DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, [DATE]) + 1, -2),
            Sales = SUM(Sales)
    FROM    Daily
    GROUP BY DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, [DATE]) + 1, -2);
```

You can use this in the same way you would the table you want create, but this will always be in sync with the daily data. If you want to change your week start/end day (i.e. monday-sunday) you can change the `-2` in the `DATEADD` function to alter this.

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6c61a/1)**

*(Based on the `[]` around column names I am guessing this is SQL-Server.)*

Comment: in this case can we group two week as one week like as follows
Sales       
1/14/2012       110

Comment: You just need to adjust your `DATEDIFF` function slightly, see the view `TwoWeekly` on [this SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/76eb4/1)